# webpack-hot-middleware is not hot replacing

Tags: webpack

Here is my server code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        // Enable logger (morgan)
        app.use(morgan('dev'));

        // Disable views cache
        app.set('view cache', false);

        var webpack = require('webpack');
        var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
        var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

        var webpackConfig = require('../client/webpack.config');
        var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

        app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath }));
        app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

    }
```

and here is my webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        './client/src/main'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'client/build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/build/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new AureliaWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: {stage: 0} },
      { test: /\.css?$/, loader: 'style!css' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff2' },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

Every time I change a source file, webpack rebuilds no problem. However, there is no hot replacement/reload in the browser...Am I missing something? I thought I followed the instructions pretty closely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: Be sure that `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` is `true`

Comment: @BobSponge Confirming that process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' is true (i.e. code execution goes into the if statement) and that there are no errors in the browser console.

Comment: @BobSponge I see an "[HMR] Connected" message in the browser console.

Comment: Stupid question: maybe it working and just make full page reload, so you always view "Connected"? Try to specify `reload` param to false: `webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=false`

Answer (score 7):

My issue was successfully resolved when I added some parameters to webpack-hot-middleware to enable HMR, and query parameters to webpack-hot-middleware/client in entry, like so:

```
//#server.js  add parameters to Enables HMR
    app
    .use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
       'log': false, 
       'path': '/__webpack_hmr', 
       'heartbeat': 10 * 1000
    }))


//# webpack.config.js:
       entry: {
         main: [
            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000&reload=true',
            './client/src/main'
              ]
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped me solve my problem with live reloading

Answer (score 1):

So my issue was actually covered in the docs. I was using the compression module upstream of webpack-hot-middleware and hadn't updated compression.

See this issue:
https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/10

Basically, if you are using compression make sure you upgrade to ^1.6. I upgraded 1.2 -> 1.6.1 and it I am getting hot reloading now.

Comment: I'm using `1.6.2` and it was not working for me. But I simply registered the middleware before the compression and it was enough. Thanks for sharing this, I spent a lot of time (days) trying to get it to work.